# How do the clock function works in operating systems?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, clock

I don't understand how clock function works within an operating system.

First the documentation for clock function in `www.cplusplus.com` is:

```
Returns the processor time consumed by the program.

The value returned is expressed in clock ticks[...]
```

As far as I understand, the clock function must access directly some register within the CPU that is a counter for CPU cycles. How is this possible? I mean, any register of 32 bits would overflow very soon if it is being incremented one unit at the CPU frecuency. Is the OS handling this overflow in some way?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter

Comment: As R..’s answer notes, a CPU-cycle counter is not needed to implement `clock`, as long as some other clock is available. However, CPU-cycle tracking can be done with instructions that retrieve the low 32 and high 32 bits of a 64-bit counter separately or with an interrupt that triggers every time the 32 bits wrap. Each time the interrupt triggers, the OS would increment its own counter for the high bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Clock ticks" are implementation-defined, not in units of the cpu clock. Historically they were fixed-length, coarse-grained scheduling timeslices. There is no need for any special hardware TSC to implement `clock`. It suffices to simply count up the timeslices the process is scheduled for (which are ultimately enforced by a timer interrupt or similar).

Comment: For scheduling timeslices, you mean, for example, the SysTick rate?

Comment: @Dan: Historically, timeslices were fixed-length (e.g. 1/100 sec on x86 Linux) and accounting was just in terms of whole timeslices. Modern Linux is a lot more complicated. In places where the 1/100 unit is still used, it's just a rounded version of some more-precise value. Unix standards [require `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to be 1 million](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html) making the `clock` function rather useless (since it rapidly overflows on systems where `clock_t` is 32-bit).